# Identifying health profiles from a large datset

Tags: factor-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I have three concepts that I am trying to relate to each other. 
**Health/Cognition/Lifestyle**

For each of the concepts I have over twenty variables from about 20,000 participants. Lets use **memory** as an example of cognition. In my data I am looking for the health profile that has the biggest negative effect on memory.
As a hypothetical example, being overweight AND having poor diet AND being over 65 years old is a worse combination then any alone.

Then I want to identify what lifestyle behavioral variables moderate these effects to protect memory. For instance, what combination of behaviors when added together form a factor that interacts with the health factor to decrease the negative effect of this health factor on memory?

Someone may be overweight, eat poorly and be over 65 BUT they play bridge, go to the theater and visit friends every day. The combined effect of these lifestyle behaviors minimizes the negative effect of the health factor on memory.

Can someone help me to identify the correct path for addressing these questions please?

As far as I know SEM and PCA help identify reflective factors, the shared variance between variables. I am interested in effects(variables) that combine to create a formative factor.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would first start by working on creating a graph based on their theorized impacts using contextual knowledge and existing literature. This doesn't have to be SEM per se. Doing this may also help you speculate on the relationship between variables. For Example if you have cross-sectional data do you really know if Bridge and theater effect memory or would memory effect them, or is there a cyclical relationship? Once you have this, exploring clusters and MAYBE effect modification between clusters will be easier.

Without background information your analyzes will not be guided by some semblance of reason and unintuitive/unacccurate things may surface.

Comment: I completely agree. I am currently thinking about ways of performing  exploratory analyses. I have in mind theoretical models which I plan on testing. What I want to also do is to try and find profiles that may be unexpected. They may be counter-intuitive and possibly make no sense (except in a statistical way). But I could use a split-half approach to train a model and then test it.

Comment: If you have enough data, the training and testing approach is always a great idea!